# What is the difference between the owners in the details tab in properties of file explorer and the advanced button in the security tab?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

In File Explorer, when you right click on a file and select `Properties` and navigate to the `Details` tab, at the bottom, there is a owner listed. There is also an owner found by going to the `Security` tab, and then clicking the `Advanced` button. Sometimes the owners in these two tabs are different. Why is that and what do each owner mean in their corresponding tabs? Are they owners of different aspects of the file?

Comment: I have never encountered such a case. Please add screenshots that demonstrate it.

Comment: I think OP is talking about file metadata, which is what is shown on the Details tab, and then the Security owner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One is metadata for the file and is dependent on the file type supporting that metadata, and the other notes who has primary security rights over the file.

For instance, a document file can have an owner, usually the person who first created the file, and it can also have a, possibly different, security owner who has primary security rights over that file on the storage.